# javafx clicking on button by codes

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

i want to click the button from a function.

i know this is possible in java applications we use

```
jButton1.doClick();
```

Is there any thing in javafx to do same work

please help me

thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using `fire()` on the button.

```
jButton1.fire();
```

Comment: no  i want to run action event of a button from another function without clicking on button

Comment: Why do you want to call the 'action' of button from a function ? You can just keep the code inside another method and call it from the function ! The same method you call also trigger from the `action` of button !

Comment: by we can do this in java application `jButton1.doClick();` so why not in javafx

Comment: The reasoning behind this is if you want to use onMouseClicked (which is more specific) for activating your button, instead of onAction. If you want to trigger your button being clicked, by some other way than clicking the mouse (such as pressing enter), you cannot call your function since it's a MouseEvent instead of an ActionEvent. Not sure what the fix is, just thought I would clarify the problem.

Comment: Aight. If your situation is like my comment above, and you want to use the enter key to trigger a button, do the following: First, make your actual button method parameterless, and point all event triggers to that method. If you need some objects like the stage, extract them in the event method, then pass them to the button method. For me, I needed to switch windows on a button press, so I had to extract my Stage from the event, and pass it to a window-switching method. Might also help to have button method return T/F if it succeeds.